# keccak256 returns 0x000000000000000

Tags: signature, cryptography, keccak

I am using the keccak256 hashing algo to retrieve a message for a signature however I am getting the return value above.

Here is the code:

```
function adminAuthorizedSwap(string price, string quantity,
    string sellerAddress, uint8 adminV, bytes32 adminR,
    bytes32 adminS) public payable returns(address, uint, uint, bytes32)
{
    bytes memory prefix = "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n54";
    bytes32 agreementHash = keccak256(prefix, price, "|", quantity, "|",  sellerAddress);
    //if the agreement hash matches then the trade can take place
    bool agreementIsValid = ecrecover(agreementHash, adminV, adminR, adminS) == admin;
    return(ecrecover(agreementHash, adminV, adminR, adminS), parseInt(price, 0), 
        parseInt(quantity, 0), agreementHash);
}
```

price, quanitity and sellerAddress are all cast as strings.

The values passed to the function are: **"100000000", "1", "0xFE6d4bC2De2D0b0E6FE47f08A28Ed52F9d052A02", 28,"0x023409a3bfeaa29209c72704a9ad3e9b95abf14f329c4582155d5533103e00d5", "0x699a3597749ac2ae016ed9fdc31c7f73b70d0a8860d7ffd68d32564957c4c38b"**

please note that the message length is hardcoded for this example as I was testing a fixed message.

Here are the return values:

```
{
   "string price": "100000000",
   "string quantity": "1",
   "string sellerAddress": "0xFE6d4bC2De2D0b0E6FE47f08A28Ed52F9d052A02",
    "uint8 adminV": "28",
    "bytes32 adminR": "0x023409a3bfeaa29209c72704a9ad3e9b95abf14f329c4582155d5533103e00d5",
    "bytes32 adminS": "0x699a3597749ac2ae016ed9fdc31c7f73b70d0a8860d7ffd68d32564957c4c38b"
}
 decoded output     {
    "0": "address: 0x56953edcc55c834bf26fdfe00aba302b09c00202",
    "1": "uint256: 100000000",
    "2": "uint256: 1",
    "3": "bytes32: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

Comment: Please provide complete enough code to reproduce the issue. This does *not* reproduce it, but of course I'm just guessing values: `return keccak256("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n54", "1", "|", "100000000", "|",  0x1234567890123456789012345678901234567890);`.

Comment: Does the function work if you pass in a simpler value? What does keccak256(5) return for example?